# Undefined x in the code

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am new to MATLAB and I am trying to run the Optimization Toolbox. 
On running the code ,

```
function f = objfun(x)
f = exp(x(1))*(4*(x(1)^2)+2*x(2)^2);

x0 = [-1,1];
options = optimset('LargeScale','off');
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fminunc(@objfun,x0,options);
```

I get the following error ,

> ??? Input argument "x" is undefined.
>
> Error in ==> square at 2
>   f = exp(x(1))*(4*(x(1)^2)+2*x(2)^2);

Please help me point what I am missing ..

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: The function `objfun` should either be in a different file from the main optimization function, or a subfunction (which comes after the main function in Matlab. Also, there seems to be an inconsistency in naming between the code you posted and the error-message. It seems that the objective function was called `square` in your case. Can you run the code as posted, please, and report the error?

Comment: I thought on the same line but it gave me the same error

`??? Input argument "x" is undefined.`
``
`Error in ==> objfun at 2`
`f = exp(x(1))*(4*(x(1)^2)+2*x(2)^2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error. Maybe it has something to do with the way you set up your code, or wrote it into a function?

When I put the following into a file and save it as "testJugeshOptimization.m":

```
function x = testJugeshOptimization

x0 = [-1,1];
options = optimset('LargeScale','off');
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fminunc(@objfun,x0,options);

%% subfunction objfun
function f = objfun(x)
f = exp(x(1))*(4*(x(1)^2)+2*x(2)^2);
```

And run the function as

```
x = testJugeshOptimization
```

I get the result

```
Local minimum found.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient is less than
the default value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>


ans =

   1.0e-07 *

   -0.1679    0.0773
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne Jonas ! It works perfectly now ... 
So the trick lies in declaring `x` as a function?

Comment: @JugeshSundram: `x` is the output of the function `testJugeshOptimization`. The trick is to properly define the objective function as a subfunction.